# Finding the number of elements of order $2$ in a given group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How many elements of order $2$ are there in the group of order $16$ generated by $a$ and $b$ such that $o(a)=8$ and $o(b)=2$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$?

The basic thing i do not understand is that order of the generator must be equal to the order of the group. So how can $a$ and $b$ in this case generate the given group ?

I tried something like this, as $b$ is of order $2$ it must be its own inverse. So from the given condition on $a$ and $b$ replacing $b$ by $b^{-1}$ i get that $o(ba)=2$ . SO there are at least two elements of order two. However, this answer is obviously not good enough.

Comment: The group you're considering is *not* cyclic; not even abelian, actually.

Comment: You're missing the one given by a alone. If a has order 8, a^4 has order 2

Comment: Try to prove that the group elements are precisely the items $a^ib^j$ where $0\le i\le7$ and $0\le j\le1$.

Comment: @egreg if the group is "generated" by some element it have to be cyclic. that is the definition. am i getting it wrong somewhere ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: What element do you think this group is generated by? You have two listed...

Comment: @AmanMittal: A cyclic group is one that is generated by **one** element. Your group is generated by _two_ element, which is something different.

Comment: But order of a generator must be same as that of the group. how can the two given elements generate this group then ?

Comment: @AmanMittal There is no guarantee that $ab = ba$. They may be different. Thinking about it, this group reminds me very much of the symmetry group on the octahedron...

Comment: @AmanMittal: "order of a generator must be same as that of the group" is only true for cyclic groups. You group is not cyclic.

Comment: @Arthur: We actually know they are different since $ba=a^{-1}b$ is given. Since $o(a)=8$, $a\neq a^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you know dihedral group $D_8$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Isn;t any group which is generated by an element cyclic by definition ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: Yes, but **your group isn't generated by one element.**

Comment: @HenningMakholm Please bear with me, i think i have missed an important concept. But a cyclic group can have several generator ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean the question mentions that the given group is "generated" by both $a$ and $b$

Comment: @AmanMittal: Yes, a cyclic group can have several possible generators. But each of these generators will generate the group _alone_. In your case neither $a$ nor $b$ generate the group alone; you need to use _both_ before the group is generated.

Comment: @AmanMittal: A cyclic group needs one and ONLY one generator. It might have several elements that generate the group (such as in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, both $1$ and $2$ generate the group), but you only need $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok i get that now. That is what confused me. "And" in the question meant they both taken together. Thanks. there will be some $a^ib^j$ of order $16$ that will be able to generate this group. Some hint towards the answer please :)

Comment: @Clayton Yeah, i got that point. Some hint towards the answer please.

Comment: @AmanMittal: No, there _won't_ be any $a^i b^j$ that generates the group. If there was such an element, your group would be cyclic, but **your group isn't cyclic**.

Comment: Also remember that a finite cyclic group has **exactly** one unique subgroup of each order that divides the group's order, so the answer to your question's title is "either one or none", depending on...

Comment: @HenningMakholm then what does it mean to use "both" before the group is generated ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: That the group is generated by $a$ and $b$ means that every element of the group can be written as a product of some number of $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, and/or $b^{-1}$ in some sequence.

Comment: @AmanMittal, your group can be given as $$G=\langle\;a,b\;;\;a^8=b^2=1\;,\;bab=a^{-1}\;\rangle$$ This is one member of the famous family of dihedral groups, namely $\;D_8\;$ . Perhaps you should google it...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $ba^{j}ba^{j}$ for $0 \leq j \leq 7.$

Answer (score 0):

It's a group, so there's some identity element $1$. The order of $a$ is $8$, so $a,a2,…,a8=1$ are all distinct. The order of $a^2$ is $4$ since $1=a^8=(a^2)^4$ but $a^4$ and $a^6$ are not $1$. Since the order of $b$ is $2$, $b≠a$ and $b≠a^2$. Continue this process and work out a multiplication table.

Answer (score 0):

$a^4;b;ba;ba^4$ are the four members of order $2$ of the given group
given group $G=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6,a^7,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3,ba^4,ba^5,ba^6,ba^7\}$

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to have mathematic formating.